# filter through scope array ignoring certain items

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope array called `$scope.groups`

```
$scope.groups = [{
                  id: 1,
                  name: "Group 1"
                 },
                 {
                  id: 2,
                  name: "Group 2"
                 }]
```

When I updated one of the groups I need to check if that updated group exists in the groups array however when i filter the array it checks the group i need to update as well so it outputs "Group exists".

```
 function ifGroupExists(GroupName,GroupId) {
            var match;
             match = $scope.groups.filter(function (item) { return angular.lowercase(item.name) === angular.lowercase(GroupName); });

                if (match.length > 0) {
                    console.log("group exists");
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    console.log("group does not exists");
                    return false;
                }


        }
```

This code works if im adding a totally new group to the array however how do i edit this so that it doesnt check the group currently being updated and have it so it only checks the other groups to see if there is a match.

Can someone help? Im sure there is a simple way to do this. Just cant seem to figure it out..

Comment: Is it possible to add a plunkr / jsfiddle or something simular?

Comment: So, you have an array and you want to add item if it is not present in the array. Is that you want to do?

Comment: No that part is working. However, i want to update one of the existing items such as group 1.. but i cant save because it says group exists! How do i edit the filter so it ignores the item im currently editing and checks the rest of the items..

Comment: How and where are you updating your array? Where is the function `ifGroupExists` being called? Can you post your HTML part

Comment: Wait ill show in a plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be simple like, just pass the currently updating group to function as well, and ignore it in the filter.

Code should be like :

```
function ifGroupExists(groupName_filter, groupName_current) {
 var match;
 match = $scope.groups.filter(function (item) { 
   return (angular.lowercase(item.name) === angular.lowercase(groupName_filter) &&
      angular.lowercase(item.name) !== angular.lowercase(groupName_current));
 });

  return (match.length > 0); 
}
```

and I hope you need `console.log` only during development :), so return can be simplified.

Further: If you have `groupName_current as $scope` property, then use it directly, no need to pass.

Comment: Yep just to check the code. ;) . Thankyou!!  This worked.